# Warnings Data/Format specifies

Tags: c, warnings

I got some warning in my code. Is there someone who can help me?
I tried to change %d to %f but the program will then not work as I want to, like with the warnings.

Comment: The format expects an integer and a double (`%d` and `%.2f`); you pass ta double (the expression `MOVE_FORWARD * i` is a floating point number), an integer (`i`)  and a double (`MOVE_FORWARD`).  Decide what you're really trying to print and adjust the format string and/or the the other arguments accordingly.  You might need `"%.2f | %.2d | %2.f\n"`, for example.  Spaces before newlines are rarely desirable.

Comment: You're passing too many arguments for your format string.  It *looks* like you meant to write `printf("%d      |%.2f \n", i, MOVE_FORWARD * i);` - IOW, the value on the left of the `|` is the row number (`i`), and the value on the right is the movement for that row (`MOVE_FORWARD * i)`.

Comment: @Harman The comment above yours shows the fix.

Comment: You can't print an `int` with `%f`.  You can't print a `float` or a `double` with `%d`.  Simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

In the line

```
printf("%d      |%.2f \n", MOVE_FORWARD * i, i, MOVE_FORWARD);
```

You are doing three things wrong:

i) You used more arguments than format specifiers, you have 2 format specifiers and used 3 arguments namely (MOVE_FORWARD *i), (i) and MOVE_FORWARD 
, you used printf to print only 2.

ii) You used wrong specifiers, MOVE_FORWARD * i is of type double, not integer.

iii) i is of type integer not double.

The correct way should be:

```
 printf("%f      |%d \n", MOVE_FORWARD * i, i);
```

if you want to print those two.